# Encoding Issue and PHP

Tags: php, curl, encoding

I' using PHP CURL to get the page.
I post data to the page and when I output the response I get bunch of characters like this:

```
‹˙˙”MkÂ@E÷ţŠ
```

I realize this is an encoding problem.

After I set default charset to UTF-8 in php.ini the output is different but still unreadable:

```
�����Mk�@E
```

When I go to the page and manually submit the form page displays fine in a browser, but when I output trough PHP using CURL to make post and output response it is unreadable.
How do I fix this, how to set encodings and where?

Answer (score 1):

I am using CE characters and I had very similar problems before: it did not help just having all my pages utf-8 everywhere as page encoding, BUT you also need to check that all of your files - php, js, css etc. - are actually physically encoded in utf-8 too.

For this purpose I am using great Notepad++, just go to ENCODING -> Convert to utf-8

Notepad++ sometimes do not know that you saved your file(s) in utf-8 and thinks it is for example ANSI: if you do not notice that and save it like that your problem may repeat once again, so I learned somewhere this nice little trick: use that Convert to utf-8"in Notepad++ + just put this somewhere at the top of your files (I am using this for php so I show php example):

```
<?php //Útf-8 ľščťžýáíéúäôň
# YOUR SCRIPT HERE
?>
```

This way it will always be recognized as UTF-8 encoded file (without this I had from time to time problems with detecting my files as utf-8 tho they were encoded like that!)

Hope this helps a bit for those that did all right (webpages encoded as UTF-8) and still having this strange characters issues

Comment: This is really excellent advice. I will most likely use this technique sometimes. Thank you.

Comment: no problem - glad I can help cos I was struggling with this kind of problem for some time too so I know very well how you feel (done everything but still from time to time file would not be recognized as utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using `UTF8` everywhere!

**php **header()****

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

and

**`html meta` tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You can convert your input encoding to utf-8 using [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

For e.g.

```
$data = iconv("Windows-1252","UTF-8",$data);
```

You can find your encoding of the text received using [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: I have set the header and added a meta tag even though I receive complete page in which there is already meta tag with utf-8 specified. No effect. Still unreadable. mb_detect_encoding() returns UTF-8.

Comment: Solved it! I added "Accept-Encoding: utf-8" into the request header and response is readable now. Thanks fortune.

Comment: Toni rmc, I used it and it saved my life thanks :) :)